# Determine user location based latitude-longitude

Tags: math, gps, maps, coordinates, latitude-longitude

I am planing to do a system that allow user to enter a 10 values of (digits, Characters) then I can determine his location.

I would to do some mathematics stuff or anythings that allow me to convert the (latitude-longitude) to one string (digits, Characters).

Is it possible to do that if yes please give me hint how I can do it!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

At a code length of 10 characters, an [Open Location Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Location_Code) (a.k.a. “Plus Code”) gives about 14m of resolution. Usually you'd have a `+` between the first 8 and the last 2 characters, but you can infer that. You can type and find these codes easily in Google Maps.

[Geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) uses base 32 instead of base 20, so each character provides more information. 8 characters there already give you 19m resolution, the way I read Wikipedia. There is a chance you'd accidentially have obscenities in your code, though, which other codes try harder to avoid.

[Geohash-36](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash-36) uses 36 base characters, and avoids vowels (to prevent obscenities), but relies on character case. Wikipedia gives the accuracy of 10 characters as ⅙m.

All of these are well documented and probably have freely accessible reference implementations, too. You can also read about the design principles behind these.